# Storing and outputting form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm creating a URL-Shortener, but am having some issues with getting jquery form values so that I can output the shortened URL text.

[*Here*](http://pastebin.com/zWNQ7cX3) is the form I am using:

```
<form name="urlForm">
    <input type="text" name="url">
    <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
    <p>Result:
        <!-- Output area. -->
        <span id="url-output"></span>   </p>
</form>
```

And [*here*](http://pastebin.com/zHu9GCS0) is the JavaScript I am using to process the form-data:

```
 // receive the form when "submit" button is clicked
    $('form[name=urlForm]').submit(function (event) {
        console.log('form submitted');
        // get the data in the form
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            //element[attribute=value]
            'name': $('input[name=url]').val(),
        };
    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: '/createShorter', // the url where we want to POST
        data: formData, // our data object
        dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode: true
    })

        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function (data) {
            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data);

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I believe the problem lies within how I am collecting the data in the *formData* variable. But despite looking at the documentation, and several different attempts, nothing I do seems to output any relevant values. Am I taking a bad approach?

How can I parse my form for the information I need?

Comment: You would want to add an `id` to the form, and using jQuery, call `$(#yourID)`. Right now you are querying for a `outputForm` tag. Alternative: `$("form[name=outputForm]")`.

Comment: @nicovank thanks! I changed it, that problem would of caught up with me soon. Still unsure of what to do in the formData though.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` now logs?

Comment: @nicovank tried a few different things. Updated code in original question. But console.log(data) returns nothing at all. When I submit a URL it returns (bad request)

Comment: Where does the the page come from? Do you have a server set up? If yes, what does the server page, or request handler look like?

Comment: Your question is just copy from other site ,  so you need to change the url of your request link and make response data ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Snippet is non-functioning (strict security), review the <kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/km3wNni6KSzeyzSCj5WZ/)</kbd> instead. The Plunker demonstrates the use of a properly made form, the use of plain JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest()`, post to a real test server and receiving a json in response. Details are commented in Snippet.

#### SNIPPET (non-functioning)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<!--Use id and name, although name isn't used in this instance, it can be useful under different circumstances-->
  <form id='urlForm' name="urlForm">
    <input type="text" id='url' name="url">
    <!--Use an input type submit button instead, it will automatically trigger a submit event once clicked-->
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
    <br/>
    <label>Result:
      <!--Using a real output element allows you to display data with the value property or with content methods such as innerHTML or textContent-->
      <output id="urlOutput"></output>
    </label>
  </form>


  <script>
    // Reference the form
    var f1 = document.getElementById('urlForm');
    // Reference the output
    var o1 = document.getElementById('urlOutput');
    // When a submit event is triggered...
    f1.onsubmit = function(e) {
      // Prevent the form from submitting normally
      e.preventDefault();
      // reference a XHR object
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // POST to server
      req.open('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', false);
      // reference a FormData object
      var formData = new FormData(f1);
      req.send(formData);
      o1.value = req.response;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks!